# Diagnosing and debugging occasional pink frame in Metal on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, metal, metalkit

I am developing a macOS app which has a metal-backed view, based on CAMetalLayer.

It worked fine on macOS Monterey, but after I upgraded my macOS to Ventura (tried both 13.3 and 13.4), the view would randomly display a blank pink screen - as if the Metal is indicating an error or empty state. I don't get any log messages in the Console though.

Particularly, the pink screen appears after I select the app's "Enter Full Screen" command for the app. It appears only in ~1 of 10 attempts, and doesn't appear in 9 of 10 attempts. The pink screen goes away after the view renders its next frame (e.g. on mouse move).

I have tried to profile the app and catch the pink frame - particularly using `-[MTLCaptureManager startCaptureWithDescriptor:error:]`, however when I analyze the trace, everything seems to be fine - all vertexes, textures and commands are being transmitted to the GPU correctly. However, on the screen, I still get the occasional pink screen.

I wonder if anyone could give me hints as of why this might be happening and what other tools I can use to track down the problem? Or maybe it's a macOS Ventura bug?

P.S. For brevity, I'm not attaching the code, which is too large and spread over multiple files to fit here. I'm interested in general advice.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the app is tested on a M2 Pro machine, if that matters.

Comment: Also it's worth mentioning that the CAMetalLayer-backed view in question is hosted in the toolbar, so the issue is probably related to the fact that when an app switches to the full screen mode, macOS detaches the toolbar from the main window and attaches it to the separate toolbar window.

Comment: My suggestion is to add completion handlers to all command buffers and turn enhanced command buffer errors using `MTLCommandBufferDescriptor`. Pink anywhere usually means there was a GPU restart or something along those lines, and that would show up in command buffer errors.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are correct, the GPU might be restarting due to the transfer of the view from the main window to the toolbar window when the main window enters the full screen mode. I do rendering in a different thread  and probably sometimes the last rendered frame happened to arrive before the transfer of the view, so the view ended up unrendered, with no frames at all after the GPU restart.

Comment: For now I seem to have fixed the problem by forcedly rendering the frame in the main thread after the transfer and it seems to have worked. I will keep the buffer descriptor error logging facility in mind for the future, I wasn't aware of this! Thanks.